# How to stop all mediaStreams

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getusermedia, mediadevices

is there any way to generally just shut down all media streams?

I'm working with a package called wavesurfer in react and i can't stop the microphone with the given methods of the package. So i was wondering if there is anything to just cut all the audio/video devices as easily as possible?

Something like

```
if (mediaDevice === active) {
   mediaDevice.stop()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't.
You must have access to all the MediaStreamTracks that do use the device and call their [`stop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/stop) method.

Comment: okay. i asked this because i didnt get any reaction to my original post about the specific package. thanks for answering! :-)